# Hadoop Name Node format fails

Tags: hadoop

When I try to format NameNode on Hadoop, I get an error saying that the directories can't be created.

```
Cannot create directory /usr/local/hadoop_store/hdfs/namenode/current
Cannot create directory /usr/local/hadoop_store/hdfs/namenode/current


java.io.IOException: Cannot create directory /usr/local/hadoop_store/hdfs/namenode/current
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.common.Storage$StorageDirectory.clearDirectory(Storage.java:337)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NNStorage.format(NNStorage.java:548)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NNStorage.format(NNStorage.java:569)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSImage.format(FSImage.java:161)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.format(NameNode.java:990)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.createNameNode(NameNode.java:1428)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.main(NameNode.java:1553)
15/06/06 22:04:30 ERROR namenode.NameNode: Failed to start namenode.
java.io.IOException: Cannot create directory /usr/local/hadoop_store/hdfs/namenode/current
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.common.Storage$StorageDirectory.clearDirectory(Storage.java:337)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NNStorage.format(NNStorage.java:548)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NNStorage.format(NNStorage.java:569)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSImage.format(FSImage.java:161)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.format(NameNode.java:990)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.createNameNode(NameNode.java:1428)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.main(NameNode.java:1553)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Which OS are you using on your hadoop cluster??

If you're running this on Ubuntu try this..

sudo bin/hadoop namenode -format

Comment: This link has some info..

http://askubuntu.com/questions/35551/error-when-formatting-the-hadoop-filesystem

Comment: I am using Ubuntu 64 bit on AWS( Amazon Web Services)  and Hadoop 2.7.0.

Answer (score 8):

This error occurs if you have not created the `/usr/local/hadoop_store/hdfs/namenode` folder or it does not have correct permission.

1. Create the directory first. Try this in terminal:

   `sudo mkdir /usr/local/hadoop_store/hdfs/namenode`

> **NOTE:** Run this command as **hadoop user**.

2. Change permissions, if necessary.

   `sudo chown -R hadoopuser:hadoopgroup /usr/local/hadoop_store/hdfs/namenode`

   `sudo chmod -R 777 /usr/local/hadoop_store/hdfs/namenode`

Here, `hadoopuser` is your hadoop username and `hadoopgroup` is hadoop group name.

Answer (score 2):

> sudo -u hdfs hdfs namenode -format

Try this command. Follow the steps.

Hope this will help.

Answer (score 1):

type in sudo su
and then try
bin/hadoop namenode -format